# Using INVOKE and PROTO in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am creating a procedure to calculate the GCD. The code worked just fine when it was in the main procedure, when I created a separate file to try and use INVOKE, it doesn't work anymore saying that there is a stack overflow

```
TITLE GCD Calculator

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDE gcd.inc

.data

.code
GCD PROC,
    num1: DWORD,; how to use PROTO? mov eax, num1
    num2: DWORD; mov ebx = num2

mov eax, num1
mov ebx, num2

push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov eax, [ebp + 12]
mov ebx, [ebp + 8]
cmp ebx, 0
je L1

mov edx,0
div ebx
mov eax, edx
push ebx ; Overflow occurs here
push eax
call GCD

L1:

pop ebp
ret 8

GCD ENDP
END
```

if needed, this is my main funciton where i prompt the user to input two numbers, then calculates the GCD by invoking the GCD function

```
TITLE Project 4

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDE gcd.inc

.data
input1 BYTE "Enter the First Integer:", 0
input2 BYTE "Enter the Second Integer:", 0
result BYTE "The GCD of the Two Numbers is: ", 0

.code 
main PROC

mov edx, OFFSET input1
call WriteString
call Crlf
call ReadInt
push eax; pushes the first input onto stack

mov edx, OFFSET input2
call WriteString
call Crlf
call ReadInt
push eax; pushes the second input onto stack

INVOKE GCD, eax, ebx; how to use INVOKE?

mov edx, OFFSET result
call WriteString
call Crlf
call WriteDec

main ENDP
end main
```

Comment: See `masm32.chm` in the masm32\help directory.

Comment: Why do you have the `popad` instruction?  You don't have a corresponding `pushad` that would have saved the registers first.  That pop is likely underflowing the stack, causing the problem.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to remove that, i was trying to use pushad and popad to see if it fixed anything, I currently do not have popad in the code and it is still giving me overflow error

Answer (score -2):

```
.data
array DD 5 DUP (?)
average PROTO a: PTR DWORD

.code
main PROC
INVOKE average,  ADDR array
call DumpRegs
exit
main ENDP
average PROC  a: PTR DWORD
;;;;WORKING
ret
average ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27780780)